# Access / save information from metafor forest plot in meta-analysis

Tags: r

I'm wondering if it's possible to access (in some form) the information that is presented in the -forest- command in the -metafor- package.

I am checking / verifying results, and I'd like to have the output of values produced.  Thus far, the calculations all check, but I'd like to have them available for printing, saving, etc. instead of having to type them out by hand.

Sample code is below :

---

```
es <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "
b se_b
0.083 0.011
0.114 0.011
0.081 0.013
0.527 0.017
" )


library(metafor)

es.est <- rma(yi=b, sei=se_b, dat=es, method="DL")


studies <- as.vector(  c("Larry (2011)" , "Curly (2011)", "Moe (2015)" , "Shemp (2010)" )   )


forest(es.est , transf=exp  , slab = studies , refline = 1 ,  xlim=c(0,3), at = c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4) , showweights=TRUE)
```

---

I'd like to access the values (effect size and c.i. for each study, as well as the overall estimate, and c.i.) that are presented on the right of the graphic.

Thanks so much,

-Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
> summary(escalc(measure="GEN", yi=b, sei=se_b, data=es), transf=exp)
      b  se_b     yi     vi    sei      zi  ci.lb  ci.ub
1 0.083 0.011 1.0865 0.0001 0.0110  7.5455 1.0634 1.1102
2 0.114 0.011 1.1208 0.0001 0.0110 10.3636 1.0968 1.1452
3 0.081 0.013 1.0844 0.0002 0.0130  6.2308 1.0571 1.1124
4 0.527 0.017 1.6938 0.0003 0.0170 31.0000 1.6383 1.7512
```

Then `yi`, `ci.lb`, and `ci.ub` provides the same info.

Comment: Brilliant... I figured -escalc- would be involved, but couldn't figure out how...